# Powershell getting foldername like, and get the first subdirectory

Tags: powershell, command-line, scripting

I already have this script for getting the files from all subdirectories
But I can't control the depthlevel of getting subdirectories.
What I mean is, I have multiple subdirectories in my path. For example.
C:\SCRIPTS\testing\testfiles\rawfiles and under rawfiles, there's subdirectories

1. stuck_test
2. raw_testfiles1-->stuck_test
3. raw_testfiles2-->stuck_test
4. raw_testfiles3-->stuck_test
5. raw_testfiels4-->stuck_test

And what I want to do is to get the stuck_test not inside at raw_testfiles1 directory. But I don't want to specify the path. Its like I want to limit the -recurse.
Thanks in advance.
I'm really stuck here.

```
 cls

    $folderName = "stuck_test" 
    $pathtest = "C:\SCRIPTS\testing\testfiles\rawfiles"

    $gettest = Get-ChildItem -path $pathtest -filter $foldername -recurse| Select-Object -Expand FullName

    $path1 = $gettest

    $Allfiles = Get-Childitem -Path $path1 -recurse| Where {!$_.PSIsContainer}| Select-Object Fullname

    foreach ($file in $Allfiles)
        {       
           $file1 = $file.Fullname
           $foldername = Get-ChildItem -Path $file.Fullname
           $input = $foldername.Directoryname
           $Mothername = Get-Item -Path $input
           $output = $Mothername.Parent.Fullname
           $output = "$output\processed"
           Write-Host "The Filename: $file1"
           Write-Host "The FolderName: $input"

           $Getbase = (Get-Item $file1).BaseName
           Write-Host $Getbase

           "$file1" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\SCRIPTS\tester\LIST\stuck_files_list.txt" -Append


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will do what you want:

```
Function GCI-ToDepth{
Param(
    $Path = $PWD.Path,
    $Filter = "*",
    $Depth = 255
    )

    $Paths = 1..$Depth|ForEach{"{0}{1}" -f $Path.trimend('\'), ("\*" * $_)}
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Paths -Filter $Filter
}
```

It's based off the principal that you can use Get-ChildItem with * for unknown folders, so you can do `Get-ChildItem C:\SCRIPTS\testing\testfiles\rawfiles\*\` and that would actually do the opposite of what you want giving you the files in all of those subfolders but not the rawfiles folder itself. The idea is solid though. For your need you could run:

```
GCI-ToDepth -Path "C:\SCRIPTS\testing\" -Depth 3
```

That would give you the files in the folder specified, plus all subfolders of that, and anything in their subfolders, but nothing past that.

Comment: In this one, I can control the depth level of the path. But how can I show or get the files inside directory?
I run your script and what I did is like this

GCI-ToDepth -Path "C:\SCRIPTS\testing\testfiles\rawfiles" -Depth 2 -filter "stuck_test" <-- I want to access the stuck_test folder outside raw_testfiles directories

Comment: If you don't want the stuck_test inside the raw_testfiles directories the depth would be 1, and you could pipe the results to Get-ChildItem to get the files inside that folder.

Comment: Thanks for this one bro, I really appreciated it. I found a new way now to access the files. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude folders by using `-notlike` in a where-object call.

If you want to exclude only the stuck_test folder in raw_testfile1:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\testfolder -Recurse -Directory -Filter "stuck_test" | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notlike *rawr_testfile1\stuck_test'}
```

In my test scenario i only got the stuck_test folder in raw_testfile2

```
D:\testfolder\stuck_test
D:\testfolder\rawr_testfile2\stuck_test
```

**EDIT**: Reading your title again i may have misinterpreted what you want to do, if you'd like to get all subfolders to a certain depth you can use `\*` in your Get-ChildItem path

Get all folders for the initial folder and 1 subfolder

```
$myPaths = @()
$mypaths += Get-ChildItem D:\testfolder\*,D:\testfolder\*\* | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

and then our $myPaths variable looks like this

```
D:\testfolder\rawr_testfile1
D:\testfolder\rawr_testfile2
D:\testfolder\stuck_test
D:\testfolder\rawr_testfile1\stuck_test
D:\testfolder\rawr_testfile2\stuck_test
```